# Reuse a function changing a function call inside it in Python

Tags: python

I want to use a function from a module, that I cannot modify, and change a call inside it to a function giving additional parameters. What is the correct way of doing so?

Example `not_my_module` where `foo` calls `called_function(a)`

```
def foo(a):
    # ... CODE
    called_function(a=a)
    # ... CODE

def called_function(**kwargs):
    # DO STUFF
    pass
```

I want to have:

```
def foo(a, **kwargs):
    # ... CODE
    called_function(a=a, **kwargs)
    # ... CODE

def called_function(**kwargs):
    # DO STUFF
    pass
```

But since I cannot modify `not_my_module` how should it be done?

What I already considered:

- Redefining `foo` with the extra parameters and copy pasting the whole code, which I don't think is good for maintenance. Example `my_module`

```
from not_my_module import called_function

def foo(a, **kwargs):
    # Awful copy paste of code and change one line
    called_function(a=a, **kwargs)
    # ... CODE
```

- Create a new function that calls `foo` and mocks the call to `called_function` and call it with the extra arguments. Example `my module`

```
from mock import patch
from not_my_module import foo, called_function

def my_foo(**kwargs):
    with patch("not_my_module.called_function" as my_mock):
        my_mock.side_effect = called_function(**kwargs)
        foo(**kwargs)
```

Is there another way to accomplish this? Is the mocking a good practice?

Comment: You will need to define `foo` yourself, your first method.

Comment: By the look of it I'm afraid I have to agree with @James, and you'll have to define `foo` yourself, with the changes you want to have. Alternatively you could try and contact the module maintainer to include the `**kwargs` injection you want to have.

Comment: And what about the mock? is it wrong? @James

Comment: Not wrong if it works, just a really odd approach.